# Как уменьшить размер кода?

Tags: python, массивы, оптимизация

Длина кода без пробелов, табуляций и символов перевода строки = 117
Как еще можно скомкать код?

```
a = [[int(a) for a in input().split()] for _ in range(int(input()))] #Ввод (массив в массиве)
for elem in a:
    print(19*elem[1] + (elem[0] + 239)*(elem[0] + 366) // 2) #Формула
```

Ввод:

```
4 #Кол-во подмассивов
2 0
13 20
5 23
18 6
```

Массив после ввода:

```
[[2, 0], [13, 20], [5, 23], [18, 6]]
```

Вывод (элементы подмассива проходят через формулу и выводятся):

```
44344
48134
45699
49458
```

Comment: `elem` -> `e` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**119 символов**

```
a=[[*map(int, input().split())] for _ in range(int(input()))]
for e in a:
    print(19*e[1]+(e[0]+239)*(e[0]+366)//2)
```

**114 символов**

```
a=[[*map(int,input().split())][:2]for _ in range(int(input()))]
for x,y in a:
    print(19*y+(x+239)*(x+366)//2)
```

на случай, если пользователь вводит больше, чем 2 числа на строку иначе убираем `[:2]` и получаем **110 символов**

**108 символов**

```
a=[[*map(int,input().split())][:2]for _ in range(int(input()))]
for x,y in a:print(19*y+(x+239)*(x+366)//2)
```

**102 символа**

```
for x,y in[[*map(int,input().split())][:2]for _ in range(int(input()))]:print(19*y+(x+239)*(x+366)//2)
```

**98 символов**

```
for x,y in[[*map(int,input().split())][:2]for _ in'a'*int(input())]:print(19*y+(x+239)*(x+366)//2)
```